# delete specific row in python pandas DataFrame based on row comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to programming and python. I have a DataFrame that is created by pandas module. The index columns of the data set are "Rho", "Capacity", and "Model-Version". Based on these factors I ran some simulations and found the revenue for each one with 5 runs. The columns are indicating the "average", "lower-bound", and "upper-bound".

Now I want to find the best revenue for each specific Rho and capacity. So I should compare the upper bounds and lower bounds for different models. If the lower bound of a row is higher than the value of another upper bound I should delete the row which had the small upper bound.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
from pandas import *

df_rev = DataFrame.from_csv(path="revenue_total.csv", index_col=[3, 4, 5])

print(df_rev.iloc[0][2])

# removing those revenues in a class that are low:
for index1, row1 in df_rev.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df_rev.iterrows():
        if index1[0] is index2[0] and index1[1] is index2[1]:
            if row1[1] > row2[2]:
                df_rev = df_rev.drop(df_rev.index[index2])
            elif row2[1] > row1[2]:
                df_rev = df_rev.drop(df_rev.index[index1])

print(df_rev)
```

But, I know that it doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just find the maximum revenue.

```
a = [['a','a',1,5],['a','a',3,4],['a','b',5,6],['b','c',7,8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.set_index([0,1])
df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),df.index.get_level_values(1)]).max()
```

This gives the maximum value from the other columns grouped over index 0 and 1.